# Where should I put my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I would like to use the code for the auto-complete. The code is [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
<p>The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Here the suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript) a try.</p>
<p>The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

However, I cannot figure out where I should put this code. In head? In body?

Answer (score 5):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

**When to put script in HEAD**

> Scripts to be executed when they are
>   called, or when an event is triggered,
>   are placed in functions. Put your
>   functions in the head section, this
>   way they are all in one place, and
>   they do not interfere with page
>   content.

**When to put script in BODY**

> If you don't want your script to be
>   placed inside a function, or if your
>   script should write page content, it
>   should be placed in the body section.

So in your case. You can put the script in the `body`

Comment: Just a hint: using w3schools as a reference around here will cause a lot of snickering and derision. It's not an authoritative source of information; it's just a random website with information of varying quality. In particular, this advice is just weird and not really comprehensive or even accurate.

Comment: Ok. So where do you suggest looking for the correct information? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html doesn't specify best practice as far as I can see.

Comment: This is probably not the sort of thing that would ever show up in a real specification. It's a matter of keeping track of good blogs and of reading good answers at sites like Stackoverflow - JavaScript performance (and client-side optimization in general) is a very hot topic lately and "best practices" opinions evolve quickly.

Comment: @Shervin Have a look at [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/). It suggests a few very good alternate resources, such as [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) (which I can highly recommend).

Answer (score 4):

You should probably put your code right at the end of the body tag.

Check out [Steve Souder's High Performance Web Sites - Evolution of Script Loading](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/12/06/evolution-of-script-loading/)

If you have multiple script includes and need to convince yourself that they will load in the correct order for you, check out [WebSiteOptimization.com's Article on the Defer Attribute](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/test/), where you can see the order your scripts execute.

Comment: Agreed.  It's good practice to declare JavaScript functions after the HTML so that the page appears to load faster.  In other words, it's a good idea to load the view first (so the user can see the page) and then load functions declarations last.

Comment: A nicely structured html page will be ordered like this: CSS at the top, HTML content in the middle, and JavaScript at the end

Answer (score 3):

Put it into external file and then link that file with HTML document using:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/my-script.js"></script>
</head>
```

(if you're using HTML5 you can skip `type` attribute).

The above way is the most clear and common one, however some researches proves that it's not the fastest way. You could put that JavaScript right before `</body>` element, skipping `jQuery.read()` (`$(function() { ... });` in this case, which is a short form of that). You'll gain some milliseconds (or even less) in that case, but I just feel forced to notice that.

Comment: John Resig doens't like that way, and I'd be careful because he reads some of these post

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should put it inside the body element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, put it at the very *end* of the `<body>` element, *after* you've included jQuery, the autocomplete plugin itself, and any other libraries you depend on. Putting scripts at the end of the `<body>` is generally (at the time of this writing :-)  considered to be a best practice because it allows the browser to get to the markup before having to worry about script execution.