# Problems calling external functions in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

I have the following javascript file under game.js:

```
var day = 1;

function new_day(){
    check_date();
    print_date();
}

function check_date(){
    if (day === 101){
        document.getElementById("the_end").innerHTML = "The End";
        document.getElementById("continue").innerHTML = " ";
    };
}

function print_date {
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day;
    document.getElementById("days_to_go").innerHTML = (100 - day);
}
```

and the following html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "game.js"></script>
    <script>new_day()</script>
    <title>New Day</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Day: <div id = "day"></div></p>
    <p><div id="days_to_go"></div> days to go.</p>
    <p><div id="the_end"></div></p>
    <p><div id="continue">
        <a href="home.html">next</a>
    </div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to check the day. If the day is 101 it says "the end" and deletes the "next" button. If it is between 1 and 100 then it prints the day and how many days are left. The problem I have is that it is not doing either of these things. Even when I change the value of day to 101 It still shows up like so:

Day:

days to go.

next

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The elements don't exist when the script is executed, wrap the script in a `window.onload = function() { /* Script Here */ }` or put the script after the elements that it references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I put my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647806/where-should-i-put-my-javascript-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place Javascript in a HTML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using jQuery to run the javascript once the document loads to allow your elements to exist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Your Code Here
}
```

EDIT: Got it to work with jQuery [JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/8z989dtr/1/)

Comment: @TinyGiant My bad, I got it to work with jQuery and now op knows that's an option, I'll try to get it to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to be put after the HMTL `body`

```
<body>
      <p>Day: <div id = "day"></div></p>
    <p><div id="days_to_go"></div> days to go.</p>
    <p><div id="the_end"></div></p>
    <p><div id="continue">
        <a href="home.html">next</a>
    </div></p>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  var day = 1;
new_day();
function new_day(){
    check_date();
    print_date();
}

function check_date(){
    if (day === 101){
        document.getElementById("the_end").innerHTML = "The End";
        document.getElementById("continue").innerHTML = " ";
    }
}

function print_date() {
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day;
    document.getElementById("days_to_go").innerHTML = (100 - day);
}
//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `<script>` tag below your code in HTML. In your program, when it loads `game.js`, it doesn't know your HTML code, and doesn't change your HTML.
This is how your code should be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Day</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Day: <div id = "day"></div></p>
    <p><div id="days_to_go"></div> days to go.</p>
    <p><div id="the_end"></div></p>
    <p><div id="continue">
        <a href="home.html">next</a>
    </div></p>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "game.js"></script>
<script>new_day()</script>
</html>
```